# how to pass parameters to ng-event handlers in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a piece of code like this:

```
Module.Article.directive('article', function ($compile) {
 return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

    var el = angular.element('<div></div>');

    scope.showNum = function(i){
      console.log(i);
    };

    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      el.append('<span ng-mouseover="showNum(i)">' + i + '</span>');
    }

    $compile(el)(scope);
    element.append(el);
}
```

and I want to get this result:

```
<div>
  <span ng-mouseover="showNum(1)">1</span>
  <span ng-mouseover="showNum(2)">2</span>
  <span ng-mouseover="showNum(3)">3</span>
  <span ng-mouseover="showNum(4)">4</span>
  <span ng-mouseover="showNum(5)">5</span>
</div>
```

but instead I get such result:

```
<div>
   <span ng-mouseover="showNum(i)">1</span>
   <span ng-mouseover="showNum(i)">2</span>
   <span ng-mouseover="showNum(i)">3</span>
   <span ng-mouseover="showNum(i)">4</span>
   <span ng-mouseover="showNum(i)">5</span>
</div>
```

Does anybody know how to pass i to the showNum() handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this, so the actual `i` variable gets printed instead of the letter i:

```
Module.Article.directive('article', function ($compile) {
 return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

    var el = angular.element('<div></div>');

    scope.showNum = function(i){
      console.log(i);
    };

    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      el.append('<span ng-mouseover="showNum(' + i + ')">' + i + '</span>');
    }

    $compile(el)(scope);
    element.append(el);
}
```

Edit: I agree that the other answer offers more flexibility, this answer points out a minor mistake in the way the person who asked the question was trying to implement it though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ng-repeat` to render `template` and pass value, only you need to create a `items` array inside your directive link function, `ng-repeat` will take care of rendering part of the html.

**Directive**

```
Module.Article.directive('article', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    template: '<div>' +
                 '<span ng-repeat="i in items" ng-mouseover="showNum(i)">{{i}}</span>'+
              '</div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      var el = angular.element('<div></div>');

      scope.showNum = function(i) {
        console.log(i);
      };
      scope.items = [];
      for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        scope.items.push(i)
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/x2cAkPZJfsd8XayfZeY2?p=preview)

Comment: Agree, much cleaner.

Comment: But it will replace my element by template, and I need to appand to the element

Comment: @Dmitry while you were doing .append it was one as the same thing..check developer console for this and old implementation.

Comment: I've checked and it has replaced my element by this template. Or there is some parameter I may to add for append to the element instead of replacing?

Comment: @Dmitry look at updated answer..basically you were creating a div by your own..so you need to mention that div in your `template` option of directive

Comment: downvoter, may I know reason behind downvote? anything wrong with mine answer?